# Line coordinates from plane intersection

Tags: plane-geometry, crystallography

Say we are given two planes denoted by their (h1, k1, l1) and (h2, k2, l2) Miller's indices.

How to find the equation which will represent the line that is the intersection of these two planes?

Comment: Does an atom lie on the line of intersection?

Comment: Yes,  particles are always on intersections.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is assuming you know an exact position of the particle. MI are nothing but direction ratios. If the line is an intersection of both the planes then its drs must be perpendicular to the normals of the plane , (h1,k1,l1), (h2,k2,l2) . So let drs be l,m,n then these can be found out by using l.h1+m.k1+n.l1=0 and same with other set of MI. know you know the exact coordinates $(a,b,c) $ of an atom . Thus equation of the line is $\frac {x-a}{l}=\frac {y-b}{m}=\frac {z-c}{n}=k $. Hope it helps!